# Which things to consider for decisions about marriage in Fire Emblem:Awakening?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I understand that the decision which character marry decides some initial attributes and skills for the child, but shouldn't it in the end of no importance? As I understand each character has max attributes and I can gather all the skills if I advance through the different classes. Or is there something else to consider?

So who should I marry to whom, to influence what? Is it important at which time they marry or something else to consider?

Comment: You're missing the fact that until your team marries, their kids (and them joining you) do not exist.

Comment: Yeah, I want my characters to marry, I'm asking if different matches or different times for marriage (or something else) has any impact on the kids that is relevant. I rephrased the question, sorry for the vagueness of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Children inherit a number of things from their parents. You correctly identify their initial attributes and the skill which their parents have equipped in their last active slot (Chrom is an exception as he will always pass down Aether to his daughters and Rightful King to his sons), but they will also inherit a few other things.

Firstly, only certain characters can have children. They are as follows:

- Chrom
- Avatar
- Lissa
- Sully
- Miriel
- Sumia
- Maribelle
- Panne
- Cordelia
- Nowi
- Tharja
- Olivia
- Cherche

Each of these characters will bear one child. If two of these characters marry, like Chrom and Sumia, then they will bear two children (Chrom's child and Sumia's child). The gender, character, and starting class of each child is fixed with the exception of Avatar who's child will always be the *opposite* gender of Avatar and the starting base class of the Avatar's mate (with the exception of Lord and Dancer which will default to Tactician).

On the inheritance front, Children will inherit stat modifiers and growth rates from their parents. This will ultimately determine their maximum potential and how quickly they can reach it. In the grand scheme of things, this has little impact, but it certainly doesn't hurt to keep them in consideration when trying to breed a child with specific traits or maximizing stats. Children will also inherit their parent's classes, *excluding* gender specific classes, like Pegasus Knight, and will directly determine their skill pool.

As a cosmetic effect, children will inherit their hair color from the parent who does not determine the child. That is, Avatar's child will *always* inherit the hair color of their other parent, never Avatar.

When deciding marriages, it's completely up to you; the only mechanical reason for picking some pairs over others is for selectively breeding children for certain skills or stats. Outside of that, you are perfectly free to decide your own pairings.

As for when to marry, you are free to marry anyone at anytime with the exception of Chrom who's relationship needs to be determined by the end of Chapter 11 for plot reasons. If Chrom is not married, he will marry the character he has the highest support level with (excluding Lissa). If his supports are at the same level, then he will marry the unit which requires the least support points to reach the next rank. If after then there is still a tie, then he will marry the highest female in this list:

1. Sumia
2. Sully
3. Maribelle
4. Avatar
5. Olivia

Even then, there are some special cases. If he has at least two support points with Oliva, she is unmarried, and he does not have a C support with any other available female, he will marry Olivia. Even further, if he hasn't gained any support points with any females or there are no available females, he will marry a generic maiden.

You will automatically recruit Chrom's child at the end of Chapter 13. Additionally, all children who have married parents will also be unlocked for recruitment. If a child-bearing character isn't married at this point, their child will be unlocked when they are married. If they're never married, their children will *never* be unlocked.

Besides from slight changes to support conversations with the generic parent, nothing else is inherited from parents.

Comment: I just started the chapter where Chrom's child is born. This is a very interesting answer! Just to be sure I understand it completely: All those people MUST be married by the end of chapter 13 or I won't be able to recruit them, right? Is there a way to accelerate the process of getting married? Like, pairing a lot the couple? Any suggestion would be great!

Comment: @vianna77 None of those characters need to be married by the end of Chapter 13. The end of that chapter is just a trigger to unlock the missions where you can recruit their children, so if a couple is married by then, their child mission will unlock. If they aren't married by then, then their child mission will unlock as soon as they are married.

Comment: Oh, thank god! :) I got a little scared after reading your answer!

Comment: after some reading, I understand that Chrom and his wife should be married and they both need to have the skills they plan to pass to Lucina by chapter 13. That's the only kid you have to worry about regarding the main storyline. All the other children can be "avoided" and better planned because they are inside sidequests.

Comment: what if Chrom has two supports of the same level? say, 2 C or B supports. what happens then? ( i can't name anyone because i haven't played Awakening)

Comment: @BlazingTrio If Chrom has the same support level with two units, he will marry the one that requires the least amount support points to get to the next level. If there is a tie even after that, he will marry the one highest in the following list: Sumia, Sully, Maribelle, Avatar, Olivia. I will update the answer with this info.